# How to create an issue comment on a pull request?

Tags: python, github-api, github3.py

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325449/why-arent-conversation-comments-in-a-pull-request-being-returned-from-pullreque/31361405#31361405) a PR is just an issue with some things on top.

How to get the associated issue id?

I just saw [issue_url](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/pulls.html#github3.pulls.PullRequest.issue_url) as attribute for the pull request object. 
Also, PR has the method `create_review_comment` but no method `create_issue_comment`.

How would such a method look like?

How to create an issue comment in the Pull Request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to do it by getting the issue from the PR number. Indeed, in github a "hidden" issue is created every time you create a pull request.

So the following code worked:

```
gh = ... # Connection
repo = gh.repository(user, repo_name)
pr = repo.create_pull(description, base, from_branch, detailed)
issue = repo.issue(pr.number)
issue.create_comment(comment)
```

One could also use [other ways to get the issue from PR number](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/examples/issue.html#example-issue-to-comment-on).

Not sure if there is any way more straightforward than this

Comment: I've created two issues for this on the github3.py bug tracker. Thanks providing insight into this use case.

Comment: If you're interested in contributing, let me know. I'm happy to provide guidance and early feedback

Comment: I would be glad in submitting some pull requests if you are willing to accept then, it might make things more agile to me

Comment: I released 1.0.0a2 yesterday. Most of the changes were contributed by people who are not me. ;)

Comment: I had to do: `issue = repo.get_issue(pr.number)`

Answer (score 8):

This works for me with current pygithub:

```py
from github import Github

g = Github(GITHUB_TOKEN)
repo_name = 'Org/repo'
repo = g.get_repo(repo_name)
pr = repo.get_pull(PR_NUMBER)
pr.create_issue_comment('test')
```